# How to create More than one single file upload Click the 'Add field' button for entity and select type 'file' for the new attribute in magento

Tags: magento

How to create Magento admin custom module click add field button for entity select type 'file' for the new attribute

This is form code:

```
$fieldset->addField('uploadpdf', 'file', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('promotionsoffers')->__('Upload PDF'),
        'name'  => 'uploadpdf',

    ));`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of [Multiple File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post#answer-10164816)

To achieve similar through Magento's Form Library, we will modify its code a bit in this way

Modify `getElementHtml` method of lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php

```
public function getElementHtml()
{
    if($this->getType()=='file' && $this->getMultiple())
        $_multiple = ' multiple';
    $html = '<input id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'" name="'.$this->getName()
         .'" value="'.$this->getEscapedValue().'" '.$this->serialize($this->getHtmlAttributes()).$_multiple.'/>'."\n";
    $html.= $this->getAfterElementHtml();
    return $html;
}
```

and then just pass new attribute `multiple=>true` in you field declaration like this

```
$fieldset->addField('uploadpdf', 'file', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('promotionsoffers')->__('Upload PDF'),
    'name'  => 'uploadpdf[]',
    'multiple'=>true
));
```